# How do I access an element in a list item within a key of a dict?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I currently have a JSON file which outputs a wide range of weather data. I can refine the information I want to a certain degree but need to refine it one step further but am unable to.

I have tried selecting it based on location e.g [1] and I have also tried to access the data based on keys e.g.  ['weather'] but I can only refine it so much before Python throws an error.

```
{'coord': {'lon': -1.98, 'lat': 50.72}, 'weather': [{'id': 803, 'main': 
'Clouds', 'description': 'broken clouds', 'icon': '04d'}], 'base': 
'stations', 'main': {'temp': 293.6, 'pressure': 1022, 'humidity': 64, 
'temp_min': 292.15, 'temp_max': 294.82}, 'visibility': 10000, 'wind': 
{'speed': 5.1, 'deg': 230}, 'clouds': {'all': 75}, 'dt': 1559214671, 
'sys': {'type': 1, 'id': 1401, 'message': 0.0072, 'country': 'GB', 
'sunrise': 1559188945, 'sunset': 1559246925}, 'timezone': 3600, 'id': 
2640101, 'name': 'Poole', 'cod': 200}
```

The above code is the JSON file that I have to work with, I want to refine and extract for example the 'main' value in 'weather' so I would like to extract the string 'Clouds' but I have tried things like dict['weather]['main'] but it simply throws up an error.

Looking for some advice :D

Comment: What's the expected output ? Can you add it to the question

Answer (score 5):

The value for `weather` is a list, so you'd need `dict['weather'][0]['main']`.

Also, I recommend not calling a particular dictionary `dict`, because it hides the built-in `dict` function.

Comment: Damn, I sometimes hate how simple the solution is.... I can't believe out of everything I tried this wasn't one of the solutions. Thanks a bunch!